# Add a next and prev button to my gallery

Tags: jquery, button

I need a bit help from someone with jquery skills. 
My problem is i got a small 6x thumbnails like pictures below.
I added 6x empty pictures. I want to limit that 6x pictures when i add 7 or more pictures and jump with next-prev button to next pictures.

The Gallery picture is ; http://hizliresim.com/ZDLrp3

The html code is ;

```
<div class="content">
                    <h3>Photo Gallery</h1>
                     <hr/>
                      <ul id='da-thumbs' class='da-thumbs'>
                            <li><a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li> 
                            <li>
                                <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title 2" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title 3" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title 4" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title 5" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title 6" href="images/photo.jpg">
                                    <img src="images/square.jpg" alt="image" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                            
                        <div class="previous">
                            <a href="#" class="next-prev">&#8249; Geri</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="next">
                            <a href="#" class="next-prev">İleri &#8250;</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Ofcourse when i click the small thumbnail pictures, it opens big one. The Gallery trigger code is ;

```
  // PHOTO GALLERY IMAGES
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#photos').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).lightGallery({
                dynamic: true,
                caption: true,
                thumbnail: true,
                desc: true,
                speed: 500,
                dynamicEl: [
                    {
                        "src": "images/photo.jpg",
                        "thumb": "images/thumb.jpg",
                        "caption": "Michael Stark",
                        "desc": "Quem legam expetendis"
            },
                    {
                        "src": "images/photo.jpg",
                        "thumb": "images/thumb.jpg",
                        "caption": "Michael Stark",
                        "desc": "Duis de mentitum"
            },
                    {
                        "src": "images/photo.jpg",
                        "thumb": "images/thumb.jpg",
                        "caption": "Michael Stark",
                        "desc": "Duis de mentitum"
            }
        ]
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Plugin upgrades are a bit beyond the normal scope of a question here

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your html is static, so this is how I would do it:

For ul images 1 -6, add .active-da-thumbs class

```
<ul id='da-thumbs' class='da-thumbs active-da-thumbs'>
....
</ul>
```

Clone your ul for images 7 - 12

```
<ul id='da-thumbs' class="da-thumbs'>....</ul>
```

Also assign classes to your a so we can call it in js:

```
<a href="#" class="next-prev thumbs-next">&#8249; Geri</a>
<a href="#" class="next-prev thumbs-prev">İleri &#8250;</a>
```

CSS, hide all except for the active one:

```
.da-thumbs { display: none }
.active-da-thumbs { display: block }
```

And then hide and display with jQuery:

```
$('.thumbs-next').click(function() {
var currentSlide = $('.active-da-thumbs');
var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
  nextSlide = $('.da-thumbs').first();
}

currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-da-thumbs');
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-da-thumbs');

});


$('.thumbs-prev').click(function() {
var currentSlide = $('.active-da-thumbs');
var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
  prevSlide = $('.da-thumbs').last();
}

currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-da-thumbs');
prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-da-thumbs');

});
```

You may need to wrap your ul in divs, not sure how uls will react to the jQuery. Forgot to mention but if you want to use a plugin instead, try looking into the owl carousel.

Comment: Thanks for ansfer cuscus. I did everything that you said. When i click next button nothing comes with fadeout. When i click back first 6 images comes again. Any idea ?

Comment: I made an edit to the js code, the last part should be .removeClass('active-da-thumbs'); instead of .removeClass('active-slide'); same thing for .addClass.  Also you will need to wrap yours uls inside a wrapper div so that the js function doesnt go outside the wrapper. Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4f4q5yq/

Comment: It is working ! Thanks a lot mate. One last question is ; is it posible to change fadeout function with slide function ?

Comment: Yes, feel free to use slideUp(), slidedown(), or any other jquery animation function. I updated the js fiddle with an example.